# Three riddles, one solution

Tags: riddle

This puzzle consists of three riddles. For each riddle, give the solution and then, finally, the word that connects these solutions.

```
    .--.      .--.      .--.      .--.      .--.      .--.      .--.      .--.
  :::::.\::::::::.\::::::::.\::::::::.\::::::::.\::::::::.\::::::::.\::::::::.\
  ´      `--´      `--´      `--´      `--´      `--´      `--´      `--´      `


                        Take a look at my toe,
                            you could really say it's odd.
                        Hot or cold, you should know,
                            it's my temperament, not my blood.

             --<<O>>--<<O>>--<<O>>--<<O>>--<<O>>--<<O>>--<<O>>--<<O>>--

                        If you know me, I'm very deep
                            but not sweet to your taste.
                        With time or in a heartbeat,
                            I give life or lay waste.

             --<<O>>--<<O>>--<<O>>--<<O>>--<<O>>--<<O>>--<<O>>--<<O>>--

                        Though I have no head, have no hands,
                            everything I'll be shaking.
                        More than water or desert sands,
                            everything I'll be shaping.


    .--.      .--.      .--.      .--.      .--.      .--.      .--.      .--.
  :::::.\::::::::.\::::::::.\::::::::.\::::::::.\::::::::.\::::::::.\::::::::.\
  ´      `--´      `--´      `--´      `--´      `--´      `--´      `--´
```

Comment: Maybe some kind of hint could get it further?

Comment: @oleslaw Like I said in chat, at the moment I'm not sure this question deserves hints. I mean if I was asking in person, maybe, but having Internet search at your disposal, it makes it very dangerous to give a hint for 3 riddles. :P

Answer (score 9):

First riddle:

> **Thermometer**(?): the "toe" of a traditional thermometer is an "odd" (not even) thing - as well as it is quite "odd" (unusual) because its not specifically a toe. By the look at it you can say if its cold or hot. My "blood" is mercury, and you can see the "temperament" - a clue to think of "temperature".

Second riddle:

> **Water**: is deep, is not sweet, with time it gives life and in a heartbeat it may lay waste (tsunami)

Third riddle:

> **Wind**: has no hands or head, causes stuff to shake, and corrode, so it shapes stuff more than water or sand.

As to the final answer:

> **Pressure** (as Patrick suggested). Thermometer works by changes in pressure of mercury. Water at large depths has quite big pressure. Wind is caused by difference of pressure of the air.

Comment: Good attempts! :D You're on the right track. Keep at it!

Comment: It seems to me that the connecting theme might be pressure, though saying that is a bit of a stretch since the second riddle doesn't relate much to it... thermometers work through thermal expansion which is essentially a change in the pressure of mercury, and wind works due to differences in pressure in the atmosphere. I can't explain the connection thoroughly for water though in the context of that riddle. Maybe in the metaphorical sense: i.e. the pressure to evolve or to survive catastrophe.

Comment: @Patrick Roberts Actually the 2nd riddle says: "I'm very deep" - water at large depths has quite big pressure.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts The link could be a hurricane, water temperature rises, causing winds?

Comment: What about "meteorology"? Assuming that your first three answers are correct, that would certainly fit. Temperature, rainfall, wind speed... all central parts of meteorology. Submitting as a comment as I don't think it's enough new information for me to take credit for.

Comment: You've got something right, but you're missing important details that let you figure out the answer. :)

Answer (score 5):

Annoyingly partial answer:

First riddle:

> Don't know.

Second riddle:

> This must be *the sea or ocean*. Very deep, check; not sweet but salty; life may well have begun in the sea or by its side, but tsunamis and the like can be devastating.

Third riddle:

> This seems like it could describe either *wind* (which shakes trees etc. and is arguably responsible for more erosion than water or sand) or *earth movements* (earthquakes in the first half, plate tectonics in the second; both are kinda the same phenomenon).

Connecting theme:

> Seems like it is going to be either *waves* (suggested by the decorative borders at top and bottom; oceans have them, and earthquakes are basically large-amplitude sound waves propagating through the earth) or *classical elements* (we have earth and water, so perhaps the first riddle leads to air or fire in some way I'm not yet seeing).

Comment: Nice answer. The decorations for the riddles are just that, decorations. In other words, no related to the solution. I just like good presentations. But you're on the right track for the solutions. Keep working on it!

Comment: You've got something right, but you're missing important details that let you figure out the answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

Common theme:

> classical elements. The missing one is AIR.

First riddle:

> maybe FIRE? I'm not sure how the "toe" part works, but certainly you should know whether fire is hot or cold: it's hot by nature, not just its blood like warm-blooded or cold-blooded animals.

Second riddle:

> WATER, specifically SEA: it's deep and salty; with time it can give life (whales, fish, seaweed, etc.), or in an instant it can lay waste (tsunamis).

Third riddle:

> EARTH: it shakes in earthquakes and quite literally shapes the world, more so than water or sand, which can both be seen as fluids.

Comment: This sounds very convincing, but what about that "toe"? :) I can't make this part clear enough...

Comment: (This seems to be essentially a subset of my answer...)

Comment: @Gareth Sorry, I didn't realise you'd mentioned classical elements too! I just looked at your solutions to the three riddles and thought I had enough new stuff (e.g. a solution to the first one, and an overall solution) to be worth posting a new answer. (I'd already been looking at the riddle, without being logged in, before any answers were posted here - I didn't just copy from yours.)

Comment: It's OK -- no hard feelings or anything. I just thought it was amusing. Great minds think alike, etc., etc.

Comment: You've got something right, but you're missing important details that let you figure out the answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

First riddle:

> Horse

Second Riddle:

> Sea

Third riddle:

> Wind

Connection:

> I don't know (it may be racing since there is a horse named 'sea wind')

Comment: Please can you explain *why* these solutions are correct, i.e. how they fit the lines of the riddles as stated in the question? Answers without explanation may be removed.

Comment: Also, please use spoilers. :D

Comment: You've got something right, but you're missing important details that let you figure out the answer. :) You should come back!

Answer (score 1):

First riddle

> Lava toes. They flow oddly and active ones can resemble a cut bleeding from skin

Second riddle

> The sea. It's salty not sweet, and very deep. Water obviously is the key to all life. A tidal wave can happen quickly and destroy life

Third riddle

> Earthquakes shake everything and shape the land

Common word

> Seismic

Comment: You've got something right, but you're missing important details that let you figure out the answer. Keep working on it!

Answer (score 1):

There have been answers similar to this but here's my take on it:

**First Riddle:**

> Volcanic Eruptions

Take a look at my toe,

you could really say it's odd.

> The foot of the volcano can be odd looking? I'm not sure about this one.

Hot or cold, you should know,

> The foot of a volcano (pre-lava) isn't all that hot, but once the red stuff comes down it's a lot warmer.

it's my temperament, not my blood.

> Erupting is something people when they're angry.

**Second Riddle:**

> Tsunami

If you know me, I'm very deep

> They come from the ocean (quite deep).

but not sweet to your taste.

> Salt water is anything but sweet.

With time or in a heartbeat,
I give life or lay waste.

> Water is a source of life, Tsunami destroy miles and miles in an instant.

**Third Riddle:**

> Earthquakes

Though I have no head, have no hands,

> Earthquakes have an epicenter no head or hands.

everything I'll be shaking.

> They shake things.

More than water or desert sands,
everything I'll be shaping.

> They change the landscape more than erosion.

They're all:

> Natural disaters

Comment: You've got something right, but you're missing important details that let you figure out the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a shot in the dark here:

> Water

First riddle:

> The end of a glacier is called is [Glacier Terminus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glacier_terminus), or toe. It's not what we normally think of as a toe, but it's one nonetheless. It's very cold, and, clearly, that doesn't stem from blood, as it has none, so it is neither cold-blooded or warm-blooded. However, you could say it has a nasty "temperament."

Second riddle:

> As it has been said before, this seems to refer to an ocean. It's salty, not sweet, gave birth to primordial life given much time, and lays ruin to buildings in a heartbeat, as [Hurricane Matthew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurricane_Matthew) is doing at the time of this writing.

Third riddle:

> It's been suggested that this is wind. I think it might be rain. The pounding of rain can shake just about anything, and the erosion of rain shapes lots of things, such as [giant landforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erosion#/media/File:Rummu_aherainem%C3%A4gi2.jpg), [water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drop_impact#/media/File:Water_drop_001.jpg), and sand (harder to find an example of this one).

Comment: You've got something right, but you're missing important details that let you figure out the answer. Think harder! :P